# Python insert tuple into mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I'm trying to insert this tuple into a mysql table.

extract of the tuple:

```
('2022-06-29 04:50:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 10:58:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 10:59:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 11:01:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'),...
```

This is my code:

```
    import MySQLdb
    
    connexion = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="myuser", password="mypass", database="mydb")
    cursor = connexion.cursor()
    table = mytablename
    
    cursor.execute("""insert ignore into " + table  + "(collection_date, var1, var2, value) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""".format(",".join(str(i) for i in tuples)))
    connexion.commit()
```

But i got this error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'" + table  + "(collection_date, var1, var2, value) values (\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'\' at line 1')
```

Many thanks for any help,

BR,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forget some `"` here:
`into "` and here `"(collection_date` so you have `into " + table  + "(collection_date` and not `into your_table_name(collection_date`

And at the end, the format doesn't work, you should concatenate your join

I let you check

```py
tuples = ('2022-06-29 04:50:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 10:58:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 10:59:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value'), ('2022-06-29 11:01:00', 'var1', 'var2', 'value')
table = "mytablename"

print("""insert ignore into """ + table  + """(collection_date, var1, var2, value) values """ +  ",".join(str(i) for i in tuples))
```

**Edit**

Looking a bit more thanks to Matthias' comment, the correct way looks like this to avoid [sql injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It's more secure

```py
cursor.executemany("insert ignore into " + table  + "(collection_date, var1, var2, value) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", tuples)
```

Comment: ho, very sorry this stuping thing.. bigger it is, many thanks for your help Pompedup

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us!

Comment: You forgot to mention that you never never never should construct a query like this, if you don't want to make SQL injection possible. Use a parameterized query instead. That's what the second parameter of the `execute` method is for.